# How to perform chroot with Linux namespaces?

Tags: chroot, namespace

After reading about Linux namespaces I was under the impression that they are, amongst a lot of other features, an alternative to chroot. For example, in [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/689856/):

> Other uses [of namespaces] include [...] chroot()-style isolation of a process to a portion of the single directory hierarchy.

However, when I clone the mount namespace, for example with the following command, I still see the whole original root tree.

```
unshare --mount -- /bin/bash
```

I understand that I am now able to perform additional mounts in the new namespace that are not shared with the original namespace and thus this provides isolation, but it is still the same root, e.g. `/etc` is still the same for both namespaces. Do I still need `chroot` to change the root or is there an alternative?

I was expecting that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/simulate-chroot-with-unshare) would provide an answer, but the answer only uses `chroot`, again.

#### EDIT #1

There was a now deleted comment that mentioned `pivot_root`. Since this is actually part of [`linux/fs/namespace.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/namespace.c#n3107), it is in fact part of the namespaces implementation. This suggests that changing the root directory only with `unshare` and `mount` is not possible, but namespaces provides an own - more clever - version of `chroot`. Still I do not get the main idea of this approach that makes it fundamentally different from `chroot`, even after reading the source code (in the sense of e.g. security or better isolation).

#### EDIT #2

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153665/per-process-private-file-system-mount-points). After executing all the commands from the answer I have separate /tmp/tmp.vyM9IwnKuY (or similar), but the root directory is still the same!

Comment: Regarding the difference between `pivot_root` and `chroot`: I took a look at the Docker sources and found that if it fails executing `pivot_root`, it falls back to `chroot`, i.e. these mechanisms are considered to be at least similar in functionality for containerization purposes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Entering a mount namespace before setting up a `chroot`, lets you avoid cluttering the host namespace with additional mounts, e.g. for `/proc`.  You can use `chroot` inside a mount namespace as a nice and simple hack.

I think there are advantages to understanding `pivot_root`, but it has a bit of a learning curve.  The documentation does not quite explain everything...  although there is a usage example in `man 8 pivot_root` (for the shell command).  `man 2 pivot_root` (for the system call) might be clearer if it did the same, and included an example C program.

### How to use pivot_root

Immediately after entering the mount namespace, you also need `mount --make-rslave /` or equivalent.  Otherwise, all your mount changes propagate to the mounts in the original namespace, including the `pivot_root`.  You don't want that :).

If you used the `unshare --mount` command, note it is documented to apply `mount --make-rprivate` by default.  AFAICS this is a bad default and you don't want this in production code.  E.g. at this point, it would stop `eject` from working on a mounted DVD or USB in the host namespace.  The DVD or USB would remain mounted inside the private mount tree, and the kernel would not let you eject the DVD.

Once you've done that, you can mount e.g. the `/proc` directory you will be using.  The same way you would for `chroot`.

Unlike when you use `chroot`, `pivot_root` requires that your new root filesystem is a mount point.  If it is not one already, you can satisfy this by simply applying a bind mount: `mount --rbind new_root new_root`.

Use `pivot_root` - and then `umount` the old root filesystem, with the `-l` / `MNT_DETACH` option.  ([You don't need `umount -R`, which can take longer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418100/umount-r-on-bind-mounts-takes-a-non-neglible-amount-of-time-why)).

Technically, using `pivot_root` generally needs to involve using `chroot` as well; it's not "either-or".

As per `man 2 pivot_root`, it's only defined as swapping the root of the mount namespace.  It isn't defined to change which physical directory the process root is pointing to.  Or the current working directory (`/proc/self/cwd`).  It happens that it *does* do so, but this is a hack to handle kernel threads.  The manpage says that could change in future.

Usually you want this sequence:

```
chdir(new_root);            // cd new_root
pivot_root(".", put_old);   // pivot_root . put_old
chroot(".");                // chroot .
```

[The postition of the `chroot` in this sequence is yet another subtle detail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/457040/chroot-before-pivot-root-causes-busy-error/457041#457041).  Although the point of `pivot_root` is to rearrange the mount namespace, the kernel code seems to find the root filesystem to move by looking at the per-process root, which is what `chroot` sets.

### Why to use pivot_root

In principle, it makes sense to use `pivot_root` for security and isolation.  I like to think about the theory of [capability-based security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security).  You pass in a list of the specific resources needed, and the process can access no other resources.  In this case we are talking about the filesystems passed in to a mount namespace.  This idea applies generally to the Linux "namespaces" feature, though I'm probably not expressing it very well.

`chroot` only sets the process root, but the process still refers to the full mount namespace.  If a process retains the privilege to perform `chroot`, then it can traverse back up the filesystem namespace.  As detailed in `man 2 chroot`, "the superuser can escape from a 'chroot jail' by...".

Another thought-provoking way to undo `chroot` is `nsenter --mount=/proc/self/ns/mnt`.  This is perhaps a stronger argument for the principle.  [`nsenter` / `setns()` necessarily re-loads the process root, from the root of the mount namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452386/29483)... although the fact that this works when the two refer to different physical directories, might be considered a kernel bug.  (Technical note: there could be multiple filesystems mounted on top of each other at the root; `setns()` uses the top, most recently mounted one).

This illustrates one advantage of combining a mount namespace with a "PID namespace".  Being inside a PID namespace would prevent you from entering the mount namespace of an unconfined process.  It also prevents you entering the root of an unconfined process (`/proc/$PID/root`).  And of course a PID namespace also prevents you from killing any process which is outside it :-).

Comment: This already helps a lot. Still, I am unsure what you mean by "the mount at the top of the namespace". And is there a way to change it?

Comment: Are you sure with the order "Usually you want to chroot() and chdir() yourself immediately before the actual pivot_root() system call."? If I chroot() first, then pivot_root() fails with EBUSY.

Comment: Yes, you are right. "An easy way to ensure this is to  change  their  root  and current working directory to new_root before invoking pivot_root()." Still, even though the new root is a tmpfs, it returns EBUSY only if I do a chroot() before the pivot_root(). https://pastebin.com/mzr0WSn1

Comment: @koalo edited :-). ps i don't know why you would need fstab for "make-rslave" / "make-rprivate". systemd's switch-root.c just does `mount(NULL, "/", NULL, MS_REC|MS_PRIVATE, NULL)`

Comment: Oh, that was just a bad assumption after looking what `mount --make-rslave /` does. Using NULL works fine :-)

Comment: This is extremely confusing. There are at least three different roots (not not mention the root user), including "per-process root", "root of the mount namespace", "root filesystem". This is not your fault, but is already in the kernel sources (e.g. as you mentioned, chroot uses set_fs_root to set the per-process root, but the fs implies that it refers to "root filesystem"....)

Comment: @koalo it is indeed. I think process root v.s. mount namespace root are the two main things.  The term "root filesystem" as used in `man 2 pivot_root`, "moves  the  root filesystem of the calling process" seems quite baroque to me... it means the filesystem mounted at the process root.  There might not even be a filesystem mounted at the process root, e.g. after entering a simple `chroot`.  I suppose it's a valid definition, but I wouldn't rely on someone knowing the same definition.  And unfortunately "root filesystem" is the one term out of these which is most commonly used elsewhere.

Comment: @koalo and then the linux kernel developers used "rootfs" when they named a fourth thing :-P. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152029/why-is-there-no-rootfs-file-system-present-on-my-system/455136

Comment: This answer and others by @sourcejedi have been exceptionally helpful, I would have asked **"pivot_root: can't umount put_old as busy"** but the answer was already here, be lazy as force won't work `umount -l ./oldroot`

Comment: FYI I've found the command-line tool *jchroot* which automates this *pivot_root(2)* technique. I've verified on Linux 3.13 and 4.18 that the *chdir("..")* escape technique doesn't work with this *pivot_root(2)* technique as used by *jchroot* in https://github.com/vincentbernat/jchroot/blob/3ad09cca4879c27f7eef657b7fa1dd8b4f6aa47b/jchroot.c#L125

Comment: Recently there was an update to the [pivot_root(2) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html) with several clarifications, and it now includes an example program. You might want to update your answer to reflect this? The man page now also explains the nice `pivot_root(".", ".")` trick, which is actually the easiest way to use `pivot_root` in most circumstances (no `chroot` necessary).