# Understanding how mount namespaces work in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, namespace, virtual-file-system

I am reading about [mount namespaces](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/) and see:

> in a mount namespace you can mount and unmount filesystems without it affecting the host filesystem. So you can have a totally different set of devices mounted (usually less).

I am trying to understand [linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces#Mount_(mnt)), and LXC and such, but I don't quite understand what that statement above means.

What I'm trying to understand is how a container (1) can have files like this:

```
/foo/a.txt
/foo/bar/b.txt
```

And another container (2) can have files like this:

```
/foo/a.txt
/foo/x.txt
/foo/bar/b.txt
/foo/bar/y.txt
```

Where `/foo/a.txt` and `/foo/bar/b.txt` on containers (1) and (2) are the same *path*, but perhaps they have different content:

```
# container (1)
cat /foo/a.txt #=> Hello from (1)

# container (2)
cat /foo/a.txt #=> Hello from (2)
```

This would mean that the files on the physical system (which I don't know anything about) are stored in one way, perhaps scattered all around. But then there is a centralized database of "virtual" files *in the operating system*, like this:

```
db:
  container1:
    foo:
      a.txt: Hello from a from (1)
      bar:
        b.txt: Hello from b from (1)
  container2:
    foo:
      a.txt: Hello from a from (2)
      x.txt: Hello from x from (2)
      bar:
        b.txt: Hello from b from (2)
        y.txt: Hello from y from (2)
```

Then there is *another* OS database for the physical files which might look like this:

```
drive1:
  dir1:
    foo:
      a.txt
      bar:
        b.txt
  dir2:
    foo:
      a.txt
      x.txt
      bar:
        b.txt
        y.txt
```

So when you create a file in the container, you are actually creating 2 new records:

1. 1 for the drive-level physical files map
2. 1 for the container-level virtual files map

This is how I imagine it to work. This is how I can see there being a way to (1) present the user (in an LXC container or cgroup (which I don't know much about)) with *what feels like* a complete "file system", in which they can (2) create their own fully-customizable directory structure (that may have the same named files/directories/paths as a completely different virtual file system), such that (3) the files from multiple different virtual file systems / containers don't override each other.

Wondering if this is how it works, or if not, how it actually works (or an outline of how it works).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

mount namespaces differ in the arrangement of *mounted filesystems*.

This is very flexible, because mounts can be bind mounts of a sub-directory within a filesystem.

```
# unshare --mount  # run a shell in a new mount namespace

# mount --bind /usr/bin/ /mnt/
# ls /mnt/cp
/mnt/cp

# exit  # exit the shell, and hence the mount namespace

# ls /mnt/cp
ls: cannot access '/mnt/cp': No such file or directory
```

You can list your current set of mounts with the `findmnt` command.

In a full container, the root mount is replaced and you work with an entirely separate tree of mounts.  This involves some extra details, such as the `pivot_root()` system call.  You probably don't need to know exactly how to do that.  Some details are available here: [How to perform chroot with Linux namespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456620/how-to-perform-chroot-with-linux-namespaces)