# How to create a chroot from which root cannot escape using chdir("..") on Linux, inside a filesystem?

Tags: linux, chroot, container

I have a directory `/var/mychoot` on the same filesystem as `/`, and I've started the program `/var/mychroot/prog` as `sudo chroot /var/mychroot /prog`, so the program is running as EUID 0.

If the program executes the [chdir("..") escape technique](http://linux-vserver.org/Secure_chroot_Barrier#Using_chdir.28.22...22.29_many_times), then it is able to escape the chroot and see everything within `/`. (I've verified this on Linux 4.18.)

I want to prevent such an escape. In fact I want to prevent all kinds of chroot escapes, but in this question I'm only interested in how the [chdir("..") escape technique](http://linux-vserver.org/Secure_chroot_Barrier#Using_chdir.28.22...22.29_many_times) can be prevented on modern Linux systems. For this I'm looking for alternatives of the *chroot(2)* system call.

I've found 2 solutions: [pivot_root](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/4769cdf607b0d1cbd73e5407d9655da7511fe193/libcontainer/rootfs_linux.go#L693) and [MS_MOVE](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc/blob/4769cdf607b0d1cbd73e5407d9655da7511fe193/libcontainer/rootfs_linux.go#L750), but they only work if `/var/mychroot` is a mount point, so they fail if `/var/mychroot` is just a subdirectory within the `/` filesystem. Is there another solution in this case?

I want to avoid techniques using `LD_PRELOAD` (because `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't affect statically linked executables), techniques using *ptrace(2)* (because then I'm not able to run `strace` within the chroot, and also *ptrace(2)* is very tricky to get right: processes will crash or hang) and real virtualization (e.g. Xen or KVM or QEMU; because of the performance overhead and the less flexible memory provisioning).

To recap, I need:

- an alternative of *chroot(2)* system call,
- with which root can restrict processes running as root (EUID 0),
- to a subdirectory of the filesystem of `/`,
- which prevents the [chdir("..") escape technique](http://linux-vserver.org/Secure_chroot_Barrier#Using_chdir.28.22...22.29_many_times),
- and doesn't use `LD_PRELOAD` or
- *ptrace(2)* or
- virtualization (e.g. Xen, KVM or QEMU),
- and it runs on a modern Linux system,
- with and unpatched kernel.

Does it exist?

Comment: Why would you need root to run in a jail? Usually you'd drop root privileges once set up and depend on services or setuid exes for access to privileged calls and areas (e.g., network).

Comment: @melds: For example, running in a jail as root is useful if `apt-get install UNTRUSTED-PACKAGE` is run, where the the install script of the package can contain malicious code. A similar use case is `docker run UNTRUSTED-IMAGE`, the default commands of such packages run as root. Docker is not using chroot for filesystem isolation, and I'm also interested in understanding what would break if it did, and how it could be fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To protect against the specific `chdir("..")` escape technique you mentioned, you can simply drop the capability to execute `chroot(2)` again once you're chrooted to `/var/mychroot` yourself. The escape technique requires another call to `chroot()`, so blocking that is enough to prevent it from working.

You can do that with Linux capabilities, by dropping `CAP_SYS_CHROOT` which is the one needed for `chroot(2)` to be available.

For example:

```
outside# chroot /var/mychroot
inside# capsh --drop=cap_sys_chroot --
inside# ./escape_chroot
chroot(baz): Operation not permitted
```

(The second prompt inside the chroot is from a shell spawned from `capsh`. You can make it run another command with, for example, `capsh --drop=cap_sys_chroot -- -c 'exec ./escape_chroot'`.)

---

But a much better technique is to just use `pivot_root`, since it protects from many of the other possible exploits that `chroot(2)` will not protect from.

You mentioned that it only works if `/var/mychroot` is a mount point, but you can make it a mount point by simply bind mounting it into itself.

Note that you need to create a mount namespace to use `pivot_root` to create a jail, otherwise it will try to change the root of all processes in your filesystem, which is most likely not what you want here...

So the whole sequence goes:

```
outside# unshare -m
outside# mount --bind /var/mychroot /var/mychroot
outside# cd /var/mychroot
outside# mkdir old_root
outside# pivot_root . old_root
limbo# exec chroot .
inside# umount /old_root
```

(Again, many of these commands are spawning new shells. `unshare` does that, so does `chroot` itself. You can work around those by passing commands as extra arguments. In some cases you might want to pass `sh -c '...'` for a full script.)

At this point, you're inside a `pivot_root` jail in a separate mount namespace, and the fact that `/var/mychroot` is simply a directory of the original root (and not a mount of a separate device or loop device) didn't really prevent this from working, thanks to the bind mount into itself.

Running the escape code, you'll see that the jail works as expected (even though the escape code claims otherwise):

```
inside# touch /inside_jail
inside# ./escape_chroot
Exploit seems to work. =)
inside# ls -ld /inside_jail /old_root
-rw-r--r--.  1 0 0    0 Jan  5 23:45 /inside_jail
dr-xr-xr-x. 20 0 0 4096 Jul  5 23:45 /old_root
```

As you can see, still inside the jail... The exploit code is just a bit naive and assumes that as long as the operations (`chroot`, `chdir`) have succeeded, that was enough to escape the jail, which is not really the case...

So consider using this technique to create a jail that is superior to `chroot` and does not require using Linux capabilities to block operations inside it (such as creating additional `chroot`s, which might actually be useful or required for what you're actually trying to run in a jail.)

Comment: FYI I've found the command-line tool *jchroot* which automates this *pivot_root(2)* technique. I've verified on Linux 3.13 and 4.18 that the *chdir("..")* escape technique doesn't work with this *pivot_root(2)* technique as used by *jchroot* in https://github.com/vincentbernat/jchroot/blob/3ad09cca4879c27f7eef657b7fa1dd8b4f6aa47b/jchroot.c#L125

Comment: I don't think this works. Making a new user namespace gives you all capabilities within the new namespace, and then you can just chroot. AIUI you need mount namespaces to make the chroot inescapable.

Answer (score 4):

> they only work if /var/mychroot is a mount point, so they fail if /var/mychroot is just a subdirectory within the / filesystem.

You can make any directory a mount point: `mount --rbind /var/mychoot /var/mychoot`.

This step - and others that you will need - are covered here:

[How to perform chroot with Linux namespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456620/how-to-perform-chroot-with-linux-namespaces)

> In fact I want to prevent all kinds of chroot escapes

Combine the above with user namespaces.

Alternatively, `seccomp`.  This is how Docker prevents contained processes calling `mount()`, for example.  (When you mount a block device a second time, you get a second view of that filesystem, which more or less counts as an escape).  Copy Docker's list of allowed syscalls - root has lots of different ways of escaping.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/

https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/seccomp/default.json

Comment: Thank you for both the solution and the insightful links on hardening a containers and chroot environments. Unfortunately it's not possible to accept multiple answers, but you have my very keen upvote.