# pivot_root(2) causes system crash

Tags: linux, system-calls, namespace, container, sandbox

I am trying to change the root of my process to new file system that I mounted at /tmp/mount_dir and i have created another directory inside it /tmp/mount_dir/inner_mount_dir, and according to the man page pivot_root(2) there is no glibc wrapper for this system call so I made my own

```
int pivot_root(const char *new_root, const char *put_old){

  return(syscall(SYS_pivot_root, new_root, put_old));

}
```

and I call it in this code after creating the two nested directories as specified by the man page

```
fprintf(stderr,"-->Changing the process's root...");
if(pivot_root(mount_dir, inner_mount_dir)){
  fprintf(stderr,"Failed..%m\n");
  return -1;
}else{
  fprintf(stderr,"Success\n");
}
```

The system call returns a success, but the issue is that the system goes into a crashing state, first all the icons from the gnome dash are gone, i cannot interact with the system at all (the system freezes i can only change windows at first then all terminates), and the screen turns into a blank black screen with a "-" at the upper left corner as if the system is shutting down, but freezes at that state until i force shutdown.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the syscall. It modifies the mount namespace of the calling process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pivot_root() acts on the namespace.

To affect only your process (and its children), first enter a new mount namespace.  And you need to ensure the pivot_root operation does not propagate back to the original namespace, e.g. by using `mount --make-rslave /`.

[How to perform chroot with Linux namespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456620/how-to-perform-chroot-with-linux-namespaces/456777#456777)

Comment: Though I did create a mount namespace before calling the pivot_root(), I think the problem was with the namespaces itself not with pivot_root() so thanks.