# How do I unmount `dev` after mounting it?

Tags: mount, unmounting

It appears that I cannot unmount `dev` after mounting it. I am running on `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS` with `4.15.0-1052-aws`.

```
mkdir -p ~/jail/dev
pushd ~/jail
sudo mount --rbind /dev dev/
sudo umount  dev/
umount: /home/ubuntu/Code/conversations/jail/dev: target is busy.
```

**Is there some way I can unmount it without rebooting my machine?**

Alternately, is there a way I can mount it so that it is easier to unmount?

**Update**: This is the output of `lsof /home/ubuntu/Code/conversations/jail/dev`:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
kdevtmpfs  55 root  cwd    DIR    0,6     2980    2 dev
kdevtmpfs  55 root  rtd    DIR    0,6     2980    2 dev
```

Comment: @airfishey The reason you can't unmount here, is there are submounts that need to be unmouted first.  Because of `--rbind`, which is a recursive bind mount.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452771/how-to-unmount-a-recursive-bind-mount-safely / https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263972/unmount-a-rbind-mount-without-affecting-the-original-mount / https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120827/recursive-umount-after-rbind-mount

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
mount --make-rslave dev/
umount -R dev/
```

The first command is required for safety.  It will prevent the second command from unmounting subdirectories in the *original* `/dev` directory.  This is due to "mount propagation".

The second command unmounts the whole tree recursively.  This makes sure to unmount `dev/pts`, for example, before trying to unmount `dev/`.  This is what caused the "target is busy" error.

---

As an optimization, you might use `umount -l` instead of `umount -R`.  This might be useful when disassembling a whole tree of bind mounts.

[`umount -R` on bind mounts takes a non-neglible amount of time, why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418100/umount-r-on-bind-mounts-takes-a-non-neglible-amount-of-time-why)

However, care is needed if they are not all just bind mounts or virtual filesystems.  The programs that had opened files will generally still be able to access them.  Until they close them, the filesystem is still open.  However, the filesystem is "detached" immediately.  It won't clutter up the namespace anymore.  It won't show up in `findmnt` and so on.  This means you can't easily tell when the underlying device will be "safe to remove".

Comment: this issue probably appeared with systemd: [debian - systemd - Known Issues and Workarounds - Shared bind mounts](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd#Known_Issues_and_Workarounds)

Comment: @A.B That's the main reason you need the first command, yes. Note it's just following a design that comes from the kernel. The kernel just didn't update the default themselves, because they consider it very important that new kernels can still run old, unmodified userspace.

Comment: @A.B thank you so much for directing us to that debian link. It finally explains why this mess happens in the first place. We see a bunch of people suggesting `umount -l` as a fix, but just using `--make-rprivate` or (better yet???) `--make-rslave` will avoid having to use `umount -l`. In fact, if you forgot to use the `--make-r*` flags when mounting, you can still remount using the flag. No more `umount -l`

Comment: @user1593842 good point. Helped confirm I wrote my answer "too clever". I think `umount -l` is useful here, but this is debatable and it maybe made it harder to see the most important point. Edited.